# How '\0' is treated in printf?

Tags: c, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[]="\0";
    if(printf("%s",arr))
        printf("not empty");
    else
        printf("empty");
    return 0;
}
```

Here I thought that `\0` will be taken as 1 byte in the array and `printf` will return 1 byte, so not empty should be printed. But output was `empty` that means `printf` returned `0`. So how `printf` takes `\0`?

Comment: Try to `printf()` `char arr[] = "mri\0gendra";`.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: What do you want express in the contex of this question?

Comment: @alk, It means `\0` is a NULL byte and printf won't interpret it.

Comment: @alk, And what does your comment infer ? Yu-Hao has already posted something similar to what you have posted an Hour ago . So what are you trying to prove on your comment ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: `NULL` is different from a `NUL` byte. The fact that the `0`-terminator is also commonly called the `null`-terminator is a poor ambiguity, which leads to people constantly mixing up `NULL` and `NUL`. One essential difference is `NUL` uses 1 byte and `NULL` uses the size of a pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char arr[]="\0";
```

Here, the `char` array `arr` has two elements, both of them are `\0`. When you use:

```
printf("%s",arr)
```

`%s` in format specifier tells `printf` to look for a string. And `printf` found it, but it stops printing after seeing the first `\0`, which is the first character. That's why `printf` prints nothing, because `arr` is an empty string.

The return value of `printf`, is the number of characters it prints, (**not** the number of bytes of the string)in this example, `0` because it prints nothing, that's why the `if` statement leads the program to print `empty`.

Comment: What about printf("%c",arr), what will it print?

Answer (score 2):

Not so much printf, but how strings are treated. Strings are terminated by \0 and they don't "include" the \0. You are asking printf to print a string via the %s. so it prints the contents of the string NOT including the \0, and so it is empty.

Answer (score 1):

printf() function with %s read value until it find '\0', It does not read  '\0' that why it returns 0 and result is empty.

Answer (score 0):

`arr` is an array of 2 chars containing two `0` bytes. One `0` is explicitly specified and other is implicitly inserted into the string literal.

When you print a string with format specifier `%s`, `printf()` prints until it encounters a `0` terminator. Since the very first character is `0` (Note that string is terminated by the first `0` itself), `printf()` doesn't print anything.

`printf()` returns the number of characters successfully printed which is 0 in this case. Hence the `if` clause fails and the `else` clause is executed. So `empty` is printed as output.

Comment: So printf prints nothing and gives output as nothing or 0. One of the reputed books Let us c(chapter string problem no 6.7) has answer as not empty, thats why i was confused.

Comment: Well anyone can make a mistake:) But `Let us C` is *not* a good book (you can search on this site why).

Answer (score 0):

The main concept here is the return type of `printf` statement . `printf` **returns the no. of characters it is printing except any** `null` **character in the statement if any** . Here your string contains only the null value, so compiler ignores it and thus the return value of the `printf` statement inside `if` block is **0** . And hence the `else` part gets executed .